# get user rank according to the like number

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have 3 tables as below in MySQL: 
**user:** id username ... 
**post:** id user_id title .... 
**user_post_like:** id post_id user_id like_date  (every like in a separate row)

Every user can send and like posts.

Now I wanna get the specified user daily rank according to the number of likes(from user_post_like table) that the user's posts got in the last 24 hours using an SQL command.

Maybe using count command for counting the users that have more likes than the specified user.

Comment: Usually people atleast take the effort to show what they tried. Or do you simply want us to do your work for you ..  Stackoverflow is ment for questions, not to let people do your coding for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select u.username, count(l.id) as likes
from user_post_like l 
join `user` u on u.od = l.user_id
where now() - interval 24 hour >= l.like_date 
group by u.id, u.username
order by count(l.id) desc
```

and if you need a rank number too, you can do

```
select u.username, count(l.id) as likes, @rank := @rank + 1 as rank
from user_post_like l 
join `user` u on u.od = l.user_id
cross join (select @rank := 0) r
where now() - interval 24 hour >= l.like_date 
group by u.id, u.username
order by count(l.id) desc
```